# Split and add suffix and prefix to file content

Tags: command-line, 16.04, php, text-processing

I am attempting 3 things.
1# split the file into small chunks
2# while splitting I need to add some text to the start of each split file.
3# I need to add some text to the end of file of each split file.

I have a file of 2 GB on which I need to perform operations. Here is the small chunk for sample of the file I have. Please split this file as per 10 lines each.
Example of the raw file on which operation need to be done:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95c0YzclhySVZYNDQ/view?usp=sharing
I want to make each split file as a php file. Here is an example of the php file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95ZjU1WXpjTElCaEE/view?usp=sharing
I just need the newly split files to be PHP file and they should look like this:

```
<?php
$urls = array("tvproduction.agency
","http://tween.agency","http://twelve.agency","http://twenty1.agency
","http://twenty47.agency
","http://twentynine.agency
","http://twentyone.agency
","http://twentysenses.agency
","http://twentysix.agency
","http://twentyten.agency");
?>
```

I have tried `split` but it only split the file.

Comment: Many ways to do this, my personal choice would be Python, but this is more of a programming question than one about Ubuntu, so you're better asking on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Use a pastebin like http://paste.ubuntu.com instead of Google Drive for sharing text here, please.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add a sample input that would result in the the output you included in your question?

Comment: Hi Jaffer, posted my answer, based on the *textual* question. Although the text seems clear, the content of your big file ("raw") confused me a bit. Could you mention if I made the right assumption(s)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sure just let me check it ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the *question* seems totally clear, the example(s) are not totally clear to me. I will therefore stick to the description of the question.

#### Splitting a file into equal chunks, adding prefix and suffix

The script below will do pretty much exactly as you describe; it will:

- split the file into equal chunks (number of lines)
- add a prefix (as first line)
- add a suffix (as last line

Furthermore:

- the files will be named:

  ```
  split_1, split_2, split_3
  ```

  etc.
- All files will be created in the working directory of the script

#### An example

A file, like:

```
aap
noot
mies
wim
zus
jet
teun
vuur
gijs
aardappel
pinda
aap
noot
mies
wim
...
```

will be split, like:

```
something_before
aap
noot
mies
wim
zus
jet
teun
vuur
gijs
aardappel
something_after
```

etc

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# --- set the file, the prefix , suffix and chunksize below
f = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test"
prefix = "something_before"
suffix = "something_after"
chunksize = 10

# --- don't change anything below
n = 1
nfile = 1

with open(f) as read:
    for l in read:
        if (n-1) % chunksize == 0:
            s = prefix+"\n"; a = ""
        elif n%chunksize == 0:
            a = suffix; s = ""
        else:
            a = ""; s = ""
        open("split_"+str(nfile), "a+").write(s+l+a)
        if n%chunksize == 0:
            nfile += 1    
        n += 1
# add the suffix to the last file if it is "incomplete"
last = suffix if a == "" else ""
open("split_"+str(nfile), "a+").write(last)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `split_chunks.py`
2. In the head section of the script, set the path to your big file, the prefix , suffix and chunksize (number of lines to split into)

   ```py
   # --- set the file, the prefix , suffix and chunksize below
   f = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test"
   prefix = "something_before"
   suffix = "something_after"
   chunksize = 10
   ```
3. Run the script with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/split_chunks.py
   ```

#### Explanation

...will follow, need to sleep :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a little tricky to get the quoting right (I *think* because `split` invokes `bash - c ' ... '` under the hood), but recent versions of GNU `split` provide a `--filter` command that should allow you to do that - for example using `sed`

```
split -l 10 --filter='sed -e '\''1i\header text'\'' -e '\''$a\footer text'\'' > $FILE' file
```

or (even simpler), with `printf`

```
split -l 10 --filter='{ printf "header text\n"; cat - ; printf "footer text\n"; } > $FILE' file
```

---

To illustrate, given `file` generated as

```
printf '%03d\n' {1..100} > file
```

i.e. lines consisting of numbers from 001 to 100, then

```
split -l 10 --filter='{ 
  printf "header line 1\nheader line 2\n"
  cat - 
  printf "footer line 1\nfooter line 2\n"
  } > $FILE' file
```

giving output files

```
$ ls xa?
xaa  xab  xac  xad  xae  xaf  xag  xah  xai  xaj
```

with for example

```
$ cat xad
header line 1
header line 2
031
032
033
034
035
036
037
038
039
040
footer line 1
footer line 2
```